# Understanding BeginInvoke in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to implement a "long wait" dialog to show a progress bar in a window during a long operation. I know there are some stock examples of this online. I am trying to understand why mine does not work so I can learn something about threading from it.

What happens when I run this is that the breakpoint at line 1 of process.Begin is never hit. Why is that?

```
public partial class LongWaitDlg : Window
{
    private ILongWaitProcess process;

    public LongWaitDlg(ILongWaitProcess process)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Progress.Maximum = 1;

        Progress.Value = process.IsLiveUpdating() ? 0 : 1;

        this.process = process;

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => this.ManageProgress()));
    }

    public void ManageProgress()
    {

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => process.Begin()));

        while (!Dispatcher.Invoke<bool>(process.IsComplete))
        {
            double progress = Dispatcher.Invoke<double>(process.GetProgress);
            Progress.Value = progress;
            Console.WriteLine(progress);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms? If so, you should be using BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Or async/await, in .NET 4.5 onward.

Comment: Your `ILongWaitProcess` interface seems flawed.  It requres you to do a busy wait; constantly checking to see if it's done.  It should simply have an event it fires when it is complete, or have a callback that is called, or a `Task` representing its completion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your operation in another thread. `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` allows you to continue execution on the primary thread, but it shouldn't be used to start a long-running unit of uninterrupted work because doing that will block all other activities on the primary thread, including other calls to `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, and responses required to keep your UI up to date.

Annotating your source, this is what is happening:

```
public void ManageProgress()
{
    // This queues up a message to run process.Begin(), 
    // but will not begin until this function and other callers ahead 
    // of it have returned control to the Dispatcher
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => process.Begin()));

    // This is waiting on a response from process, but it will get 
    // stuck in the loop here. Also, using Dispatcher.Invoke<> is suspect here.
    // By looping here, we prevent the prior call to BeginInvoke from working.
    while (!Dispatcher.Invoke<bool>(process.IsComplete))
    {
        // ...
    }

    this.Close();
}
```

Instead of using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to launch your unit of work, consider using any number of alternatives, such as `System.Task` (async/wait in .net 4.5), `System.Threading.Thread`, or `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. All of these will allow you to schedule work outside of the primary thread, and you can use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` from outside (your work item) to schedule updates to your UI, presumably to an updated version of your `ManageProcess()` method.

[Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)
[Thread Class (System.Threading) at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)